Imagining Rational Cauchy Sequences as Dancing Around a Real Number Instead of Converging to One
I'm trying to build my intuition regarding the Cauchy-sequence construction of the reals.
Essentially, do you think that it is more accurate to visualize a real number as being defined by sequences of rationals dancing around it (but never getting to it) as opposed to converging to it (as is conventionally visualized).
The latter image of convergence threatens to 1) introduce circularity to the (albeit intuitive) conception of the Cauchy construction. This is because rational sequences are imagined to converge to a real point but we have no conception of a "real number" (or a real point). 2) Plus, real numbers are themselves (an equivalent class of) sequences, and it's mind boggling when we think about how a sequence converges to many (equivalent Cauchy) sequences. (We think of convergence as things narrowing down but here, it's exploding).
So, instead of imagining real numbers as 'the point' to which a Cauchy sequence converges, I was thinking if we can imagine real numbers as being defined by rational numbers dancing around very close to it (particularly the rational numbers at the tail ends of the real number's equivalent Cauchy sequences). So, it's like a donut. The hole is empty. We don't know what the real number (the hole) is, so we define it in terms of the breading all around that hole.
Would such an imagining be conceptually accurate?

I think this is a fine question and don't understand why it's been downvoted. I would much rather answer questions like this than homework questions; at least the OP is genuinely curious and trying to really understand something. Their language may not be precise but that's what happens when you're a student trying to understand something unfamiliar for the first time! Not something we need to punish new users for.


The latter image of convergence threatens to 1) introduce circularity to the (albeit intuitive) conception of the Cauchy construction. This is because rational sequences are imagined to converge to a real point but we have no conception of such an object of a "real number" (or a real point).

It may seem circular but it's not. It's an example of a very common move in abstract mathematics: we want to think of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers as converging to a point, but that point doesn't necessarily exist as a rational number. So, we say that we will simply use that Cauchy sequence to define the new point we want, by fiat (up to a suitable equivalence relation), and this turns out to work.
The first time you see this it seems like you are getting something out of nothing but there is real work to be done in proving that this all works and makes sense, and once we know we can do things like this we can repeat the same maneuver to define lots of other important objects such as the $L^p$ spaces.


Plus, real numbers are themselves (an equivalent class of) sequences, and it's mind boggling when we think about how a sequence converges to...a bunch of many many (equivalent Cauchy) sequences! (We think of convergence as things narrowing down but here, it's exploding).


Yes, it takes some getting used to, and ultimately it's a lot simpler just to think about a real number as being your intuitive conception of a point on a continuous line. After setting up some basic facts about $\mathbb{R}$ once in your life you will never need to think about real numbers as being Cauchy sequences; that all becomes "under the hood" stuff that can be safely ignored.

So, instead of imagining real numbers as 'the point' to which a Cauchy sequence converge, I was thinking if we can imagine real numbers as being defined by rational numbers dancing around very close to it (particularly the rational numbers at the tail ends of the real number's equivalent Cauchy sequences). So, it's like a donut. The hole is empty. We don't know what the real number (the hole) is, so we define it in terms of the breading all around that hole.

This is closer to a different construction of the real numbers using Dedekind cuts, which you may prefer. The idea is to think of a real number as being defined by all the rational numbers which are less than it, e.g. $\sqrt{2}$ is defined by the fact that a rational number $q$ is less than it iff $q \le 0$ or $q^2 < 2$. This description of what a real number is is arguably much less redundant than the Cauchy sequence description, and arguably corresponds more directly to the intuitive idea that we want to "plug in all the gaps" in $\mathbb{Q}$. It also allows, for example, very direct access to the digits: we get the first $k$ digits after the decimal point of a non-negative real $r$ by asking what the largest integer multiple of $\frac{1}{10^k}$ is which is less than $r$.
On the other hand, the Dedekind cut construction makes crucial use of the ordering on $\mathbb{Q}$, so it only generalizes to other sets which also have a similar ordering, which is uncommon. The Cauchy sequence construction instead involves measuring distances between rational numbers, which turns out to generalize in a more robustly useful way, to metric spaces; e.g. we can't get the $L^p$ spaces via a Dedekind cut-like construction, to my knowledge. So that's one reason why a class or a textbook might prefer to use Cauchy sequences; it sets up a useful example for later.

Nice answer. Just a query, are you saying that can naturally define $L^p$ spaces as the completion of another space?

@Joshua: yes, e.g. the space of step functions (with respect to the $L^p$ norm).

Imagine to live the real world in which approxination is necessary. If a measure or a computation generate a Cauchy sequence, the knowledge of the sequence equals the knowledge of the result in any approximation. The rest is a theoretical math formalization, interesting and beautiful.
